# Not able to detect an incoming call in Oreo

Tags: android, incoming-call

I am working on an Application where i need to detect incoming call in activity's onResume(), i am using this code to detect any incoming call.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
            if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                // Code 
            }
        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Moreover it's working on every device below Oreo, and on Oreo device its not working, i am not sure where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Make a broadcast receiver and declare it in the manifest file, if you need it to work even when the app is not ON, otherwise make a broadcast receiver in the activity, to make your app listen to calls(not literally listen, I think you know what I am saying).
When you create it, just type **registerReceiver(...fill your intent filters, etc here...)** in onCreate function and **unregisterReceiver()** in onDestroy() to finish it before closing the activity

Comment: have you tried it? Beacuse i have tried it, its not working that way as well

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried it. I just wanted you to explore this option, if you had not explored it.

Answer (score 0):

in Android 8 (Oreo) the broadcast receivers are limited. 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background